# Docker build: `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Tags: reactjs, docker, github-actions

Trying to implement git info as part of a create-react-app where the .git directory is in my profject folder above the client directory:

```
[project]
 - .git
 - [client]
 - [server]
```

My start and build commands:

```
"start": "REACT_APP_GIT_SHORTHASH=`git log -1 --pretty=%h` REACT_APP_BUILD_TIMESTAMP=`date '+%F_%H:%M:%S'` react-scripts start",
"build": "REACT_APP_GIT_SHORTHASH=`git log -1 --pretty=%h` REACT_APP_BUILD_TIMESTAMP=`date '+%F_%H:%M:%S'` react-scripts build",
```

Locally I am able to issue these commands no problem while I'm in the `client` directory, however when attempting to deploy with docker using Github Actions I'm getting the following:

```
> client@0.1.0 build
> REACT_APP_GIT_SHORTHASH=`git log -1 --pretty=%h` REACT_APP_BUILD_TIMESTAMP=`date '+%F_%H:%M:%S'` react-scripts build

fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

**client Dockerfile**

```
FROM tarampampam/node:17-alpine

ARG VERSION
ENV VERSION $VERSION
ARG BUILD_TIMESTAMP
ENV BUILD_TIMESTAMP $BUILD_TIMESTAMP


# Setting working directory. All the path will be relative to WORKDIR
WORKDIR /client

# Copying source files
COPY . .

# Installing dependencies 
RUN npm i -g npm@8 && npm i 

# Building app
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

# Running the app
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

Do I have to clone my git repo (private) and implement ssh just to issue this git command?

Am I missing something?

The `REACT_APP_BUILD_TIMESTAMP` is working flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

The `COPY . .` instruction will **NOT** copy dot folders/files at the root level (`/foo/.bar` will be copied, but not `.foo`).

Just add `COPY .git .` and it'll work.

Comment: `COPY .git .` will copy all content inside `.git` folder to your `WORKDIR` which will not work. But the correct copying command in Dockerfile is `COPY .git .git`.